# What exactly are the graphs of orbitals?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, orbitals

In my QM class we are finding the wave functions of the hydrogen atom. In spherical coordinates, these wave functions are functions of 3 variables: $r,$ $\theta,$ and $\phi.$ My professor stated that "*the wave functions of the electron are called orbitals*".

Say, we are interested in the $l = 0$ (or s-orbitals). Since $l = 0,$ $m = 0.$

$$\psi_{n00}(r,\theta,\phi) = R_{n0}(r)Y_{00}(\theta,\phi) = \left(\frac{1}{4\pi}\right)^{1/2}R_{n0}(r)$$

So, we can set a specific $n$ value. Say, $n = 1,$ and we get the the corresponding 1s orbital. Since we set an $n$ value, the wave function reduces to a function of the radius $r.$ During the lecture, he said that this image:

[image: isosurface of the wave function at a constant radius]

is an isosurface (or level surface) of the wave function at a constant radius. 
I interpreted that as finding the isosurface of a 4D graph, our wave function, at some radius. This isosurface is the the sphere in 3D. What confused me was when he stated that the graph was an "*isosurface of the full orbital*".

What does he mean by the "*full orbital*"? Is this "*full orbital*" something in 4D space?

Comment: No 4D! The spherical surface is mathematically 2 dimensional: it is the boundary of the 3 dimensional “ball” within. Note that ordinary language usage is *not* always the same as the mathematical language. So the spherical surface is embedded in three dimensional space.

Comment: Isn't an orbital a probability distribution?

Comment: @124c41 Someone can correct me but from what I understand, an orbital is described by a wave function. It is a region of space where an electron can be found. The probability density is the square of the wave function.

Comment: Yes it is correct. But why being the orbital a probability distribution causes your question? Graphs of the orbital can be graphs of that function (the orbital) or related functions, such as a probability density function, its square. If you want to visualize how a s changes radially, a section along a plane is better suited. A common way is to plot 2D in 3D as such that the probability to find an electron within exceed 90 percent or more. Tough usually these plots are used qualitatively l

Comment: For isocontours or isilosurfaces you just set a value to be kept. In your example is not n, but a value that lead finally to a meaningfully high probability to find the electron

Comment: @Alchimista I agree with everything you said. So I think what it boils down to is that the 'best' we can do to visualize orbitals is via these density plots (or alternatives graphs). I don't have a problem with this, but I think it is still important to make certain distinctions. Though density plots are one of the best ways to visualize, I don't want to equate it with orbitals.

Comment: As you may have surmised by now: An orbital/wavefunction is defined for all values of $r$, and in that way exists through all space (though the wavefunction has negligible value except for near the origin). The isosurface graphs are produced by picking a constant value of $r$, so that the "shape" of the orbital can be visualized intuitively. However, keep in mind that mathematically the orbital extends past the isosurface, with exponentially decreasing value. You will see this if you look at the radial factor of the wavefunction $R$, which will have an exponential decay term.

Comment: @JamesBond Strictly speaking: No, an orbital is NOT a region of space. Also, the orbital is not described by a wave function, instead it IS the wave function (of a single electron). Therefore, the probability density is actually the absolute square of the orbital. Since the wave function is never really zero, the electron could be located anywhere, and that region of space would span the whole universe. Saying an orbital "is a region of space where an electron can be found" is a simplified visualization, but imprecise!

Comment: @Feodoran Since the wave function spans the entire universe, and the wave function IS the orbital. Would it be correct to say that the orbital spans the entire universe? (Strictly speaking)

Comment: @JamesBond By that definition, yes. But I don't know whether quantum mechanics is still valid when talking about the universe as a whole. It is a theory made for the small things, not the macrocosms.